# Data validation selection to prompt alpha numeric sequence entry in adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to have a cell populate an alpha numeric sequence based on the selection from a data validation list?

For example I was hoping to be able achieve - if someone selects “Design” from the drop down, this would cause the next cell across to populate “DR134” and so on sequentially each time the “Design” option is selected i.e. if “Design” is in A1 the DR134 appears in B1.

If someone selected “Project” this would trigger “PR089” and so on instead.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `worksheet_change` event or an if statement or an if formula in the cell

Comment: Use a lookup table and a VLOOKUP() formula in ColB